# Read RSSI from sensor tag

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi

I am trying to create an iOS app that scans all the sensor´s tag in the reagion and returns the RSSI (BLE) value of each one into an variable.

Does any one have or know any template avalible?

Many thanks!

Comment: RSSI? Is that a form of RFID? Can Crapple products do that? (see what I did there, hurr hurr right? :P)

Comment: If you could provide us with a little more detail, such as which sensor you are using. This looks like Bluetooth.

Comment: It also looks like this might be of help: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html

Comment: the sensor that I'm using is a BLE sensor, from texas (TI BLE Sensor TAG) and I would like to monotorize the RSSI (dB) from the tag. many thanks